# string types not allowed (at mapType with value roadmap)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

hi I have an android app that shows where you are in google maps. It can be used with map types such as hybrid,satellite but when I tried for roadmap it gives this error

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:mapType="roadmap"
map:uiCompass="true"
map:uiZoomControls="true"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

in this code rodemap highlighted and the error occurs howver in other maptypes there is no such thing and I see that nobody has that experience before .. I am very new to android can someone please help

also here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.kodlab.nerdeyim"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.kodlab.nerdeyim.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.kodlab.nerdeyim.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission         android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>   

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.kodlab.nerdeyim.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBZpmUzeHqNZIBtk_aH1OTz7Q7gtNSWeMk" />

</application>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to be "normal" not roadmap to see the roadmap view..
cheers